# Exporting elements with alias in Typescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I would like to rename the functions that I am exporting using the following syntax.

```
export const { selectIds, selectEntities, selectAll, selectTotal } = adapter.getSelectors(selectState);
```

So that I can import `selectAll` as `selectAllThings` into other files.

Is this possible with Typescript/Javascript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes you can set alias on import stage:

```
import { selectAll as selectAllThings } from 'path_to_file';
```

or you can set alias on descructurization stage:

```
export const { selectAll: selectAllThings } = adapter.getSelectors(selectState);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
export const { selectIds, selectEntities, selectAll:selectAllThings, selectTotal } = adapter.getSelectors(selectState);
```

and then import like this

```
import {selectAllThings} from "./file"
```

Answer (score 0):

```javascript
export const selectAllThings = selectAll
```

adds an alias instead of renaming, if you still want to be able to import selectAll.